# Given a number of items, how many sets of three are there where no two sets are two thirds similar?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, combinations

Sorry if the title isn't proper math-talk. Hopefully I can explain it better here.

So let's say we have a set. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. I want to know how many groups of three can be made where no two sets have two items in common.

If (1,2,3) is one group, then no other group can have (1,2), (1,3), or (2,3).

So for nine items we can make:

```
123 
145 
167
189
246
258
269
348
379
478
```

Ten groups that follow those rules.

What about n items?

Hopefully this question is something fun!

Comment: In your example you do have a repeat: (4,8)

Comment: You can do better though, with n=9 it's possible to find 12 sets of 3 which don't have any overlapping pairs. This covers all possible pairs. Google "Steiner Triple Systems" for some relevant info.

Comment: You're right, Josh! That's what I get for not knowing how the actual math works. I looked it up, but I don't really follow. I'm only in my second year of college math.

Comment: So, Josh, is there no simple formula that takes the number of items and produces the number of triplets?

Comment: Are you trying to represent every pair in a triple, or just find the largest number of triples which do not share a pair?

Comment: Largest number of triples that do not share a pair.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure yet. I'm working out some small examples on paper now.

Comment: Thanks! Normally I can figure out questions like this with the combinatorial stuff I learned in high school. But this question is tricker. It feels like there is an answer, though.

Comment: The problem is really covering the complete graph on n vertices with as many triangles as possible. I believe this is the right sequence, [A001839](http://oeis.org/A001839)

Comment: That looks like it! Very interesting, thank you.